# Floated element dropped to next line in ie6/7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float, internet-explorer-6

i seem to be having a floating issue when floating divs inside a container that also has text in ie6 and ie7.

http://mwl.webgen.gsm.org/discussions/proin-elementum-lectus-eget-est-9/1358/

if you look at the star rating here in FF or ie8+, your see that the stars should be positioned to the left of the container text (the actual rating as a number) but as much as ive tried i cant for the life of me get it work, they just drop down underneath.

I hope this makes sense, I've spent about 4 hours trying different things, setting display to inline-block etc, but to no avail.

Comment: Yes it does. Do you mind if I re-code the whole thing?

Comment: What do you mean recode the whole thing? Unfortunately I can't change any of the mark up so it has to be a pure CSS solution :(

Comment: Ok. See my answer. In IE9 there are 10 empty text nodes just under the "div class="stars" while in IE7, there is just 1.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
<div class="stars" style="width: 150px !important; float: right;">
<span class="starsAverage" style="float: left;">
```

Comment: hmmm that seems to put the average next to the stars which is cool, but it still drops down a line but leaves the "()" on the line above.

Comment: It worked fine with me on IE7. Are you using IE9 with IE8 and IE7 mode or are you using them by standalone. How are you testing in IE6?

Comment: im using ie6 using ie tester, running ie8/firefox natively. That problem in ie9 is another issue as it seems to just show radio buttons so i dont think the javascript is working properly there.

Comment: ive updated the css in the link as you said, is that looking right for you then? i basically want it looking like, "Rating: (3) *****" all on the same line

Comment: Please have a look at this. Why the difference? (IE9) - http://i51.tinypic.com/2q9vtdg.jpg (IE7) - http://i51.tinypic.com/10o4dgg.jpg

Comment: hmmm, interesting, im not too sure is the answer to that! Would that be why its dropping down to the next line then? Also is it going to be possible to get the rating to be withing the ()

Comment: Do we have the option of not including the "(" in the first text node and ")" in the second text node, but instead put them with the 3 as "(3)" - http://i54.tinypic.com/23j1laf.jpg

Comment: That would be the ideal option aye, ill see if the rendered html can be changed in the JS ;)

Comment: And by re-code I did not mean changing the HTML markup. But instead changing the CSS by not using floats, but using positioning! Is that acceptable?

Comment: Is it possible to remove the "(" and ")" and than use span.starsFeedback:before {content="(";} and span.starsFeedback:after {content=")";}

Comment: Yeh should be able to do that

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it Mate. Please follow along.

1 - First we remove the "float: left"

```
DIV.rating .stars SPAN.starsAverage
{
float: left /*remove this*/
}
```

2 - Again we remove "float: left" and change "display: block" to "display: inline;"

```
.ui-stars-star
{
float: left; /*remove this*/
display: inline; /*changed from display: block;*/
}
```

3 - Next we change the width from "8px" to "18px" and add "zoom: 1" to each div

```
<div class="ui-stars-star ui-stars-star-on" style="width: 18px; zoom:1">
```

4 - Next we remove the "margin-left: -8px;" from the "a" within the above div

```
inline style
{
margin-left: -8px; /*remove this*/
}
```

5 - Now we change the width

```
DIV.rating
{
width: 260px;
}
```

6 - Again we change the width

```
DIV.rating .stars
{
width: 210 !important;
}
```

And Whola. Here you have it. Time Taken: 2 hours and 31 minutes. I will send you the Bill.

[Example Image](http://i55.tinypic.com/1oxied.jpg)